# Batch to Move Multiple Files For Processing

Tags: batch-file

I am moving folders of invoices into another folder where the invoices are processed by a program to make them searchable. Each folder takes less than an hour to process and I am trying to see if I can make my batch file more efficient. Currently I have it set up to move one folder at a time every hour, then to rename it when finished.

```
Move C:\cdc-pod\i1 c:\cdc-pod\MerchandiseInvoices2016
timeout /t 3600
rename c:\cdc-pod\MerchandiseInvoices2016\i1 "i1 (complete)"

Move C:\cdc-pod\i2 c:\cdc-pod\MerchandiseInvoices2016
timeout /t 3600
rename c:\cdc-pod\MerchandiseInvoices2016\i2 "i2 (complete)"

Move C:\cdc-pod\i3 c:\cdc-pod\MerchandiseInvoices2016
timeout /t 3600
rename c:\cdc-pod\MerchandiseInvoices2016\i3 "i3 (complete)"
```

It is simple enough but I need to repeat the process a few hundred times. I feel there has to be a better way to input this rather than repeating those three lines over and over, especially where I need to change the folder name when I go down the list. All of the folders are named i1-i340.

Any input is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

```
for /L %%n in (1,1,340) do (
 Move C:\cdc-pod\i%%n c:\cdc-pod\MerchandiseInvoices2016
 timeout /t 3600
 rename c:\cdc-pod\MerchandiseInvoices2016\i%%n "i%%n (complete)"
)
```

**BUT**

If you `move` the directory to the destination, its files will be placed under `...voices2016\i%%n` and the original directoryname will disappear, So - will the process you refer to detect the new files, since they are now in a subdirectory of `...voices2016` ? Your original sourcedirectoryname will no longer exist, so the renaming will generate an error.

OTOH, if you `COPY` the files in the source directory using `Move C:\cdc-pod\i%%n\*` will the name collide with one already in the destination? The original directory will remain intact and be able to be renamed.

But even there, if the filenames involved won't clash, why not simply copy all of them to the destination and process as one giant job?

Comment: Ah this one works the way I need it to. Much Appreciated!

The program being used it to look into a file and scan for .TIF files and then to load the files to make them searchable. The program we use though will freeze up if it is backed up enough where we find it works best to let it run about 500 .TIF files an hour. Instead of going over and reloading it ever hour I have just left it to be moved over automatically with this. It would be better if I could make it so that once the folder is empty then the next one is moved over but this works for me.

Thanks again!